# Why MySQL doesn't use multiple ranges for indexing

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

According to [range optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html) page of MySQL, once the optimizer sees an inequality operation, the rest of the index will not be used. Here is the full excerpt:

> For a BTREE index, an interval might be usable for conditions combined with AND, where each condition compares a key part with a constant value using =, <=>, IS NULL, >, <, >=, <=, !=, <>, BETWEEN, or LIKE 'pattern' (where 'pattern' does not start with a wildcard). An interval can be used as long as it is possible to determine a single key tuple containing all rows that match the condition (or two intervals if <> or != is used).
>
> The optimizer attempts to use additional key parts to determine the interval as long as the comparison operator is =, <=>, or IS NULL. If the operator is >, <, >=, <=, !=, <>, BETWEEN, or LIKE, the optimizer uses it but considers no more key parts. For the following expression, the optimizer uses = from the first comparison. It also uses >= from the second comparison but considers no further key parts and does not use the third comparison for interval construction:
>
> `key_part1 = 'foo' AND key_part2 >= 10 AND key_part3 > 10`.
> The single interval is:
>
> `('foo',10,-inf) < (key_part1,key_part2,key_part3) < ('foo',+inf,+inf)`
>
> It is possible that the created interval contains more rows than the initial condition. For example, the preceding interval includes the value ('foo', 11, 0), which does not satisfy the original condition.

I can't understand why the third key couldn't be used, however, because the interval:

`('foo',10,10) < (key_part1,key_part2,key_part3) < ('foo',+inf,+inf)`

would work just fine and filter out more rows. Why isn't MySQL able to consider using this interval?

Comment: Because of rows `('foo', 10, 100)` then `('foo', 11, 0)`.

Comment: *I can't understand why the third key couldn't be used* It will be used - but it will be scanned (the execution plan shows "using where" instead of "using index"). I.e. it will be used like compact table version.

Comment: @Akina, okay got it. But key_part3 is already sorted after part1 and 2. So once range check for part1 and 2 is done, checking part3 should be efficient. So why does it need to scan the whole filtered result again?

Comment: *why does it need to scan the whole filtered result again?* Where you have taken this from? The server will select a part of index which matches ```key_part1 = 'foo' AND key_part2 >= 10```, and only this part will be scanned for ```AND key_part3 > 10```.

Comment: The page I linked says the interval may produce more rows than initial conditions. So I presumed the filtered result will be scanned again for key_part > 3. But if its doing what you described, then that's optimal. But it doesn't look like it does that. I checked with a table with columns a and b, with index (a, b). where a='foo' and b > 10 is way faster than where b='foo' and a > 10. It looks like its doing a > 10, and then scanning the result for b. Its that slow

Comment: Why, you ask? It's developed by humans. Very smart and dedicated humans. But not omniscient. And it's open source. Put a feature suggestion in their bug-tracking system: [MySQL](https://bugs.mysql.com/) [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-community-bug-reporting/) Or even make a pull request if you have the time.

Comment: @O.Jones, I'm just curious and learning. Not trying to criticise

Comment: There are a zillion optimizations that are possible.  I suspect the one you describe is so far down the list that the developers have not seen a strong need and/or no see that it would help enough to matter.  When you encounter a real-life example and find that the lack of that optimization is hurting your app, file a feature request with bugs.mysql.com